# How to explain this kind of reasoning?

Tags: soft-question, education

First, sorry for the vague title, but I couldn't think of a descriptive title for this question.

I was teaching some physics to my nephew and eventually we got to the formula $$distance = speed \times time$$
I explained it to him and he agreed that the formula "makes sense" intuitively.

Then he tried to solve the following exercise: If we walk a distance of 6km in 2hours what is our speed?

He couldn't solve it. So I explained to him that he could use the formula above to deduce that $$speed = \frac{distance}{time}$$

But then he said: That makes no sense! You told me that $distance = speed \times time$, but you gave me no formula for the speed.

Well, that got me thinking. First I couldn't understand what was his doubt but then I finally got it. Here is what he meant:

Imagine you have a particle moving with constant speed on a line. If we watch it for 10 seconds we know that the particle has traveled an actual distance with certain fixed speed. We know that $d = s \times t$, where $d=$distance, $s=$speed, $t=$time. That way we can know the distance the particle has traveled in 10 seconds. **Suppose that this formula is all we know from physics**. I know that the **number** $s$ equals $s = \frac{d}{t}$, but how do I know that this $s$ is the ACTUAL distance traveled by the particle?
In other words, we know that **mathematically** $d = s \times t$ is equivalent to $s = \frac{d}{t}$, but how do we know that this last formula "is valid in physics"?

Maybe this looks like a physics question but it's not. I understand that his doubt is an example of the following question:

Imagine we have a problem we want to study (i.e, particle moving on a line) and we interpret it mathematically. How do I know that the mathematical conclusions I get about my interpretation of the problem actually reflects some property of my original problem? For example, imagine I'm trying to solve a problem about real numbers $a,b$ such that $a^2+b^2=1$, so I can interpret the problem about the pair $(a,b)$ lying on the circle of radius $1$, from that fact I can use properties of the circle to learn something about my original problem, but how do I know that properties of the circle reflect properties of my original problem?

I've been doing this kind of reasoning my whole life, so I couldn't understand why someone would not understand it, I'm just used to it. How can I explain this in a clear manner? You may answer this question using another example of such reasoning, not necessarily this physics problem.

Thank you.

Comment: to be fair, s is average speed.

Comment: It is difficult.  I remember years ago, I was driving the children of a friend home. At one point, I mentioned that we had 70 miles to go and we were doing 70mph; so, if we could maintain that speed then we would arrive in an hour.  One of the children responded: "Oh, I never knew that's what 70mph meant".  Previously, she knew that mph was a measure of speed and that bigger numbers were faster but she had not associated the speeds with time and distance.

Comment: @badjohn That is how I started to explain it to him and he finally began to understand.

Comment: Of course, we did not arrive in an hour since once we left the motorway, we had to slow down.  However, I was able to maintain the speed for long enough to compare our progress against the road signs.

Comment: I think you are confusing a definition with reality.  Speed is defined by that equation.  As other commenters have noted, there is no implication that you traveled at that speed.  Presumably you didn't.  Sometimes you were faster, sometimes you were slower.  We can try to prove a theorem that tells us that you must have moved at that speed for at least an instant, but even that isn't necessarily true, it depends on all manner of assumption.  Math is not reality...though it can sometimes do a good job of modeling it.

Comment: @lulu Do you really teach a young boy that speed is a mathematical definition? Or do you work examples with him until he is convinced that s=d/t ? I think many of you missed the point. He asked WHY s=d/t works, because he sees it as simply mathematical manipulation of symbols (i.e., algebra), he doesn't see where the physics "guarantee" him that in fact s=d/t. I think I've made it clear in the question.

Comment: Yes!  The question he posed is abstract and is going to have an abstract answer.  Physics does not guarantee that the math will work out.  The math is a model we use because it works quite well in a lot of situations, it is not reality.  I mean, you are always free to respond "don't worry about that now.  Learn how to use the operations and we'll come back to exactly what they mean or don't mean later."  But, honestly, abstract questions have abstract answers.

Comment: @lulu I see your point. But the book we are studying from begins with the equation $d = st$. I think this equation is more intuitive than any one of its derivations, i.e, s = d/t. MAYBE if we start with a definition $s := d/t$ there would be no doubt. BUT, at this level you don't want a definition to tell you something you "know" and "feel". I think that this is the whole point about $d = st$ being the first equation. I see your point, thank you.

Comment: I see.  I would argue that "distance" and "time" are intuitive.  Well, at least they feel intuitive.  Speed is confusing, all motion is confusing...look at Zeno's paradoxes of motion.  Therefore, to me it makes more sense to write $s=\frac dt$ to start....you always take the things you understand and build new things out of them.  In the equation $d=s\times t$, what does $s$ mean?  Is it defined by that equation (in which case $s=\frac dt$ by definition) or is it defined in some other way?

Comment: Side note:  I would definitely teach Zeno's paradoxes, even to very young students.  Have taught them, as it happens. They are cool and easy to understand, at least at a first pass.

Comment: The book doesn't ever define $s$ (not rigorously). We simply gain confidence through very simple worked examples.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354159/are-there-sine-waves-in-nature-or-are-they-a-mathematical-construct-that-helps-u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting philosphical question:

> Imagine we have a problem we want to study (i.e, particle moving on a
>   line) and we interpret it mathematically. How do I know that the
>   mathematical conclusions I get about my interpretation of the problem
>   actually reflects some property of my original problem?

This is classical applied mathematics or (in a way) theoretical physics. You build a mathematical model of a physical system with properties that are physically (i.e. experimentally) correct, make mathematical deductions, and hope that the mathematical conclusions match the real world so can be checked by experiment. If your model and your mathematics are good enough you've done useful work. If not, it's back to the drawing board - improve the model or do better mathematics.

But I agree with some of the other commenters that in your particular problem the issue isn't the suitability of the model. I think it's in the definition of speed. Essentially, what you measure is distance and time. Then you use mathematics  (i.e. division) to *define* the (average) speed. That means the statement 
$$
s = \frac{d}{t}
$$
is just a definition telling you how to use the word "speed". It's not a physical law, nor is the consequence that
$$
d = s \times t .
$$
That's just a tautology.

Of course when the speed is not constant (that is, when measured distance isn't proportional to measured time) you have to invent calculus.

---

An anecdote:

Years ago in the first lecture of a course on the mathematics of quantum mechanics Professor George Mackey began by drawing two big circles on the board, with arrows back and forth between them, all the while saying (but not writing) that one of the circles represented the real world and the other a mathematical abstraction. The arrow going one way was model construction, the other arrow model predictions.

Later in the lecture he returned to the metaphor, turned to point to the picture on the board and wondered (with no irony) "now which circle is the real world?"

Comment: Hah.  Many mathematicians think their world is the real one.  They even call them the *real* numbers :-)

Comment: That is a nice answer. Maybe start off by saying that $s=d/t$ as a definition is not "good practice" from a pedagogical point of view (as I said in a comment in my question), but that would certainly get rid of this kind of confusion. Thank you Ethan.

Comment: linear acceleration can be though of on linear graphs actually using a plot of velocity and time.

Answer (score 3):

His problem is probably not as philosophical as you make it out to be.  Try giving him an *example*: suppose a car travels 110 miles in two hours at constant speed.  How do you find the speed?

Comment: Yes, that is how I explained it to him, but his doubt remains a valid one. I ask here because maybe he will have this same doubt later on, I wish I could have a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

> but how do we know that this last formula "is valid in physics"?

Because mathematics is the language that we use to express models of physical (or even social) situations. The consistent mathematical rules that have been developed, originally to model "real-world" situations, have shown to give results that are in accord with the behaviour of the real world (within acceptable tolerance). So our confidence has grown that the rules for manipulating mathematical expressions will always produce results consistent with the real world. However, mathematics has grown beyond the real-world and as long as it is internally consistent a mathematical system is deemed to be correct (e.g. non-commutative algebras) even if the maths has seemingly no application to the "real world". Sometimes the "abstract" mathematical tools later come to have real world application such as group theory applied to particle physics and many others.

*Update*
I am reading [this accessible essay](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.403.3697&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by the mathematician Michael Atiyah on the relationship between mathematics and the physical world.

Comment: "Non commutative algebras" are (in a sense) central to quantum mechanics, so quite useful in the real world.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, I couldn't think of the application but I felt there was one.